# How to understand the data move from A to B in character array？

Tags: arrays

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    char a[10], b[9], c[5];
    scanf("%s", a);
    scanf("%s", b);
    scanf("%s", c);
    printf("%s\n", b);
    printf("%s %s %s", a, b, c);

    return 0;
}
```

when input c[] array's number > 5, the rest osf the characters will be wrriten to b[] array, why?

for example:

input:
program
is
wonderful

output:
rful
program rful wonderful

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1621394/how-to-prevent-scanf-causing-a-buffer-overflow-in-c

Comment: Thanks for your comment,it is useful.

Answer (score 0):

You're suffering C buffer overflow.
Try to avoid using `scanf("%s", char[])` for this purpose.

Better use `fgets()` or similar.

*Offtopic:*
Interestingly this is related on how Nintendo's Wii was cracked. Or so it says the urban legend.

Comment: Yes,I've learned that the way memory organise array in stack.It is wise that avoiding using scanf().Thanks for your advice.